# I want to get the ListViewItem name in android when clicking the image on it

Tags: android, listview, onclick

When I click the edit image on the listView item.
I put the onClickEvent on my adapter.
I want to get the position or the name of that textview through my Main Activity.

Suggestions, please?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
      if (v == null) {
          final Context context = getContext();
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.transferlistviewitem_layout, null);
      }

      TransferEntry item = transferList.get(position);
      if (item != null) {
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.transferName_textView);
                ImageView delete = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_icon);

                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        t.setText(transferList.get(position).getItemName());                                                 
                    }
              });*/
```

Comment: You do not need to post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14827368/450534

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can get text from that `TextView` on `listItem` click listener method of your
          listview. by this code :

```
 TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
```

Here v is the view of the `OnItemClick` event handler. And when you click that item you can get text by this TextView easily.

Comment: Means U have your listItem click listener method in your activity. In this method you can write your text view that you have written in your adapter .

Comment: not that way. I have an image in my listview item, and its the image i want to click, not the listviewitem directly.

Comment: You can write something like this..      ImageView img_arrow = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
       img_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
      System.out.println("on img click");
     }
    });
In your itemclick method of listView.

Comment: I want to pass it to my MainActivity.
My onClick is on my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I already know the answer.

On my Adapter Constructor, I have a parameter which is the instance of my MainActivity and set it to the instance of MainActivity in the adapter. :)

Comment: oh you already knew the answer , and you were just testing us?
how cool